# Does passing reverse=True when sorting a list in Python affect efficiency?

Tags: python, performance, sorting, reverse, time-complexity

When calling `sort()` on a list in Python, passing `cmp=f` slows down the sort. Does passing `reverse=True` affect the efficiency of the sort in any way (or is it identical to sorting without reversing)?

Comment: +0.75 for an interesting and useful question, and +0.25 for proper use of the word *affect*.

Answer (score 8):

I would guess that there is no slow down due to `reverse=True` since the result could simply be built with reversed decisions along the way. When benchmarked correctly (thanks to Duncan), this guess is borne out:

```
In [18]: import random

In [57]: x = range(1000)

In [58]: random.shuffle(x)

In [59]: %timeit sorted(x)
1000 loops, best of 3: 341 us per loop

In [54]: x = range(1000)

In [55]: random.shuffle(x)

In [56]: %timeit sorted(x, reverse = True)
1000 loops, best of 3: 344 us per loop
```

I've repeated this test a few times and with different sized lists (`N = 10**3, 10**4, 10**5`) and received consistent results.

Answer (score 8):

From my benchmarks, there appears to be a small difference:

```
import timeit

setup = """
import random
random.seed(1)
l = range(10000)
random.shuffle(l)
"""

run1 = """
sorted(l)
"""

run2 = """
sorted(l, reverse=True)
"""

n1 = timeit.timeit(run1, setup, number=10000)
n2 = timeit.timeit(run2, setup, number=10000)

print n1, n2
print (n2/n1 - 1)*100,"%"
```

Results in (on my machine):

```
38.8531708717 41.2889549732
6.26920286513 %
```

The same run, but for a list of 1000 elements:

```
2.80148005486 2.74061703682
-2.17253083528 %

# ...another round...
2.90553498268 2.86594104767
-1.36270722083 %
```

Comment: Sorting the same list every time doesn't prove a difference, because the sort time will depend on the data distribution.

Answer (score 5):

The `sort()` method is native, i.e. it's implemented in the host language rather than in Python. Passing a function in the `cmp` argument forces the native implementation to call that function and execute Python code on each iteration. That's where the performance hit comes from.

On the other hand, passing `True` in the `reverse` argument only instructs the native algorithm to sort the items in reverse. If `cmp` is not set, only native code will be involved, so the performance should be comparable to plain `sort()`.

Of course, benchmarking would tell for sure.

Answer (score 4):

Surprisingly, it takes longer to reverse-sort a list. The other answers have already shown this with nice benchmarks. I looked into the source and found the [explanation in `listobject.c`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2914ce82bf89/Objects/listobject.c#l1972):

```
/* Reverse sort stability achieved by initially reversing the list,
applying a stable forward sort, then reversing the final result. */
if (reverse) {
    if (keys != NULL)
        reverse_slice(&keys[0], &keys[saved_ob_size]);
    reverse_slice(&saved_ob_item[0], &saved_ob_item[saved_ob_size]);
}
```

So, to get a sorted output, the list is reversed before sorting, then sorted, and finally reversed again. Reversing a list is a **O**(*n*) operation, so you'll pay more and more for this, the longer the list.

This suggests that if you're building a custom key function anyway, then you can save time for big lists by negating it directly:

```
very_long_list.sort(key=lambda x, y: -cmp(x, y))
```

instead of using `reversed=True`:

```
very_long_list.sort(key=lambda x, y: cmp(x, y), reverse=True)
```

In this case, you can of course pass `key=cmp` directly in the second case and so save the extra call through the lambda function. But if you have a bigger expression, then this might pay off.

Comment: Note that if you simply negate the comparison function the reversed sort will no longer be stable. That's why Python does the reverse/sort/reverse shuffle to maintain stability.

Comment: +1 for doing the code exploration. I was still downloading the tar ball… ;-)

Comment: @Duncan: Are you sure? I don't think that's true: by definition `sort(key=f)` is stable for any `f`, including the case when `f` is a negated comparison function. It looks like the cpython code does the double-reverse so that it does not have to negate the results of the comparison function out of performance reasons, but it could do and be correct. What would be incorrect is stable sorting by normal key and then reversing (without reversing before sorting).

Comment: @sdcvvc Not, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the `cmp` arg to `list.sort` and the `sorted` built-in function are deprecated in Python 2.*x* and no longer allowed in 3.*x*, because of the poor performance they give, as you have noticed. Instead, you are supposed to use the `key` arg to define a custom sorting order.

Comment: Really, deprecated in all of 2.x? I have a book from 2.3 and 2.4 days and it's explained and encouraged.